# Prevent TeamCity building on fast-forward merge to master if build exists for that SHA1

Tags: git, triggers, teamcity

Using TeamCity in combiniation with git.
Currently, TeamCity is set up with "`master`" as the default branch.

Typically, development takes place on another branch (e.g. "`dev`") - TeamCity is set to watch for changes on "`dev`" and build automatically.

If `DEADBEEF-SOME-SHA` has been built & tagged by TeamCity as build 1.2.3.4 on "`dev`" and we fast-forward merge that git SHA1 to "`master`", TeamCity still performs a build - so we end up with `DEADBEEF-SOME-SHA` being tagged as both 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.5.

As I understand it, making "`dev`" the default branch would prevent this.
Is there another way to prevent TeamCity performing a build if a build has already succeeded for that same SHA1?

Note if we push directly to `master` (and that SHA1 doesn't exist on other branches / hasn't been built) I'd still like to see a build.

**I'd like to achieve this entirely in TeamCity if possible - no additional scripts/writing of files etc etc**.

Comment: I'd like to do this all within TeamCity - ideally all within the trigger configuration section.

Comment: This behavior also forces a completely unnecessary build which lengthens the load of the build machines for no benefit.
This is a clear case where watching for changes relatively to branches, rather comes with clear drawbacks (cf also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265182/teamcity-vcs-triggers-on-every-commit-when-branches-are-merged where another unncessary build gets triggered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply wish to restrict the branches for which builds are automatically triggered, set a branch filter for the VCS trigger:

Project settings => Triggers => VCS Trigger (edit) => Branch Filter

Set the branch filter to

```
+:dev
```

then (even though "master" is the default branch) builds will only be automatically triggered on dev. It is still possible to perform ad-hoc builds on other branches (assuming the VCS root allows it)

Comment: Interesting. More precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 5):

You can query builds for a particular SHA1... but you [have to know your previous buildID for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45784720/6309).

So what I would do is:

- write in a dedicated folder (accessible by all agents)  the sha1 built at the end of each job
- only triggers a new job if that sha1 file is not already present.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but trying to avoid more moving parts (writing of files)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I missed something :

if the commits are tagged in your repo, before starting a new build, you can check if the head commit isn't already tagged :

```
# if you use exclusively lightweigth tags :
git show-refs --tags | grep $(git rev-parse HEAD)
# also check that the tag looks like a build tag, e.g : refs/tags/1.2.3.4
   | grep "refs/tags/[1-9.]*$"

# if you use annotated tags :
git show-refs --tags --dereference | grep $(git rev-parse HEAD)
# the grepped line may look like : refs/tags/1.2.3.4^{}
   | grep -E "refs/tags/[1-9.]*(\^\{\})?$"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on where to put this? In the VCS trigger rules section?